# parse yaml data to browser using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yaml, requirejs, frontend

I have a yaml file and i want it to be read by my browser website. When I run my function in browser console, i get below error for my variable yaml

```
TypeError: yaml is undefined
```

Whereas i have declare it inside function. PFB my function

```
function parseyam() {
   var yaml = require('js-yaml');
   var fs = require('fs');
   // Get document, or throw exception on error
   const doc = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('services.yml', 'utf8'));
   console.log(doc);
}
```

I also added require.js in my index.html and tried to work around with require.js. I think the variable yaml is not working fine because of require.

Please advise, how do i make it work?

Note: When i run same code in backend, it works fine and i get data. 
Is there any other way i can make it work on front end? Any other alternatives? Would be thankful if anyone could help me here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that NodeJS uses CommonJS module format,but the RequireJS uses AMD module format. They not compatible. There are some possible solutions to fix that, please go ahead to RequireJS site to read more: https://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html

Comment: Any other way to read the data from browser end? except RequireJS? In backend we are able to do using python (i mean parsing yaml file). 
Requirement seems very simple, i just need to read data from browser. But its taking more than a week for me. :(

Comment: What about using https://github.com/jeremyfa/yaml.js.git ? They say: "Works under node.js and all major browsers" so seems to be a good candidate